# Angular 2 Route to root location from folder, not folder/

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

So I have a folder called account with the following route file:

```
import { Route, Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { Login } from './login';
import { Register } from './register';
import { Home } from '../../components/home';

export var Routes = {
    login: new Route({ path: '/', name: 'Login', component: Login }),
    register: new Route({ path: '/register', name: 'Register', component: Register }),
    home: new Route({ path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: Home })
};

export const APP_ROUTES = Object.keys(Routes).map(r => Routes[r]);
```

After a user logs in I do:

```
this._router.navigate([this.routes.home.name]);
```

But this routes to **.../#/account/home**.

I would like to route to just **/**.

I also have another problem. When I am at the login page, the link to the registration page does not work with `[routerLink]="['/Account/Register']`. If I am at any other page it works fine.

Comment: Do you use `HashLocationStrategy`? I guess you need to provide more information about your application. RootComponent with routes, and the other components involed in your routing problem (stripped from code unrelated to your question).

Answer (score 0):

```
[routerLink]="['/Account/Register']
```

should be

```
[routerLink]="['/Account', 'Register']
```